# strtod with limited string length

Tags: c, strtod

If I want to parse the first 3 characters from the char array as a double, ignoring the following characters, do I really need to do this?

```
int main() {
    const char a[] = "1.23";
    char *b = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);

    memcpy(b, a, sizeof(char) * 3);
    b[3] = '\0';

    printf("%f\n", strtod(b, NULL)); // Prints 1.20000, which is what I want

    free(b);
}
```

Isn't there a function like `strtod` that allows you to specify the maximum string length it should be searching for digits?

**Edit:** I want it to print `1.2` (which it currently does), **not** `1.23`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to only consider the three first characters from a given string, you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double parse_double(const char *str) {
  char *tmp = 0;
  double result = 0;

  asprintf(&tmp, "%.3s", str);
  result = strtod(tmp, 0);
  free(tmp);

  return result;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%f\n", parse_double("1.23")); // 1.2
  printf("%f\n", parse_double("1234")); // 123
  printf("%f\n", parse_double("0.09")); // 0.0

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a desired precision, I want it to be limited by string size, so `"1.23" => 1.2`, `"1234" => 123.0` & `"0.09" => 0.0`

Comment: @alk You take first three **characters** of the string: `"1234" => "123"`, then you convert it to a double `"123" => 123.0`.

Comment: @Tyilo: Ok, I see ... - whatever the idea behind this is, you might like to see my answer for a possible solution to this.

Comment: @Tyilo: Welcome, but are you sure you accepted the right answer though... ;->>?

Comment: @Tyilo, this is just a roundabout way of doing what you showed in the code in your question, except `asprintf()` isn't very portable and `memcpy()` is better suited for just copying bytes around. The right way to go is `sscanf()`, which I added an answer about.

Comment: Yes, this (accepted!) answer is worse than the original question...

Answer (score 6):

While `strtod()` doesn't allow you to limit the string length, you can use `sscanf()` with a *maximum field width* and an optional check for the number of characters consumed, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double parseDouble(const char *str){
    double val = 0;
    int numCharsRead;

    // Handle errors by setting or returning an error flag.
    if(sscanf(str, "%3lf%n", &val, &numCharsRead) != 1){
        puts("Failed to parse double!");
    }
    else if(numCharsRead != 3){
        puts("Read less than three characters!");
    }

    return val;
}

int main(){
    printf("%lf\n", parseDouble("1.3")); // 1.300000
    printf("%lf\n", parseDouble("1.5999")); // 1.500000
    printf("%lf\n", parseDouble(".391")); // 0.390000
    printf("%lf\n", parseDouble(".3")); // Read less than three characters!\n0.300000
    return 0;
}
```

`sscanf(str, "%3lf%n", &val, &numCharsRead` is the important part: you specify a maximum width of 3, which means that `sscanf()` will read *up to 3* characters for that particular field, and also store the number of characters consumed by the end of the parse in `numCharsRead`. You can then check that value if you care about reading exactly 3 characters every time; if you're fine with 3 or less, you can just use `sscanf(str, "%3lf", &val)`. For reference, here's the documentation for width specifiers:

> An  optional  decimal  integer  which specifies the maximum field width.
>   Reading of characters stops either when this maximum is reached or when a
>   nonmatching character is found, whichever happens first.  Most conversions
>   discard  ini‐ tial  white  space  characters (the exceptions are noted below),
>   and these discarded characters don't count toward the maximum field width.
>   String input conversions store a terminating null byte ('\0') to mark the end
>   of the input;  the maximum field width does not include this terminator.

Comment: Nice, except 2 points.  1) With `str == " 1.3"`, --> `numCharsRead == 4` and `val == 123`.  The `3` in `"%3lf%n"` limits up to 3 the number of charters scanned _and used in the conversion_.  `%n` reports the number scanned, used in conversions or not.  2) `val` is not defined on the fail path.  Try `printf("%lf\n", parseDouble("xyz"));` first.

Comment: Yeah, the first one's a very good point. I didn't bring it up but it caught my eye in the documentation; the only solution there is to probably manually skip over any whitespace in the string. As for `val` being undefined, you're right, but that was just meant to be a simple example. In reality you'd probably want to structure that function differently, setting or returning an error flag if it fails to parse.

Comment: Not that determining `val` count is important to OP's goal, but code could use `" %n%3lf%n", &before, &val, &after`

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't such a function in the standard library.

But it's fun to roll one's own:

```
/*
 * Same as strtod() but only takes the first n characters into account.
 * Additionally returns 0. and sets errno to EINVAL if 'nptr' is NULL.
 */
double strntod(const char *nptr, char **endptr, size_t n)
{
  double result;

  /* perform input validation */
  if (!nptr)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;

    result = 0.;
    if (endptr)
    {
      *endptr = nptr;
    }

    goto lblExit;
  }

  if (strlen(nptr) <= n)
  {
    /* Nothing to truncate: fall back to standard 'strtod()' */        
    result = strtod(nptr, endptr);
  }
  else
  {
    /* create working copy of string */
    char * ptmp = strdup(nptr);

    /* Test whether 'strdup()' failed */
    if (!ptmp)
    {
      result = 0.;
      if (endptr)
      {
        *endptr = nptr;
      }

      goto lblExit;
    }        

    /* truncate working copy to n characters */
    ptmp[n] = '\0'; 

    /* do original 'strtod()' on truncated working copy */
    result = strtod(ptmp, endptr);

    /* adjust '*endptr' to point to original character array, but to working copy */
    if (endptr)
    {
      *endptr = nptr + (*endptr - ptmp); 
    }

    /* free working copy */
    free(ptmp);
  }

  lblExit:

  return result;
}
```

Comment: What do the backticks do?

Comment: @JL2210 which backticks?

Comment: @JL2210: Ah. They were a typo. Thank you for fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `strtod` is like this

```
   double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

The function will return the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr`. If `endptr` is not `NULL`, a pointer to the character after the last character used in the conversion is stored in the location referenced by `endptr`.

So it does not let you specify the number of characters that need to be converted. Hence you have to modify your input itself and pass it to `strtod`.

Comment: I already knew that. I'm asking if there is another function, which provides the functionality I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation that i got working without `malloc` or `strdup` and other memory allocation functions whatsoever:

```
double strntod(const char* str, size_t len) {
    double d = 0.0, j = 0.0;
    
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c == '.') { j = 1.0; continue; }
        
        d = d * 10.0 + (double) (c - '0');
        if (j > 0.0) j *= 10.0;
    }
    return d / j;
}
```

Note that it assumes that all characters in `str` up to `len` are numbers or a dot, and that there is at most one dot in str.